# REST call from client side on GWT and avoid cross-domain restriction

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, gwt

I developed a WEB application using Google App Engine and GWT that makes REST calls to a internal [RT](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/REST) service inside my company. I used for that the [RT-Rest](https://github.com/bboksa/RT-REST) API making the calls from the server side.

The problem came when, for internal security reasons, we have to use a VPN to access to this RT service, so that the calls from App Engine Server are not allowed. I decided to move this logic and make the calls from the client side, as far as everyone should have the VPN up on their computers. But as we are working in different domains I found the problem of cross-domain calls not allowed (CORS).

At this point I am stuck, I cannot make the calls from the server because the VPN inconvenience nor from the client side because of the CORS. And I don't have access to modify the REST service to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response.

Everything says that there is not very much things I can do, but maybe I am missing something or someone has a good idea to solve the inconveniences and make the calls to the RT service.

Any suggestion will be very useful. Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you use Google's Secure Data Connector to access your VPN-protected data through App Engine? https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/docs/1.3/overview

Comment: Here it is said that I have to install SDC inside the intranet, that I don't have permissions 
[link](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/docs/1.3/installing)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Secure Data Connector to connect AppEngine to services behind a firewall :

https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/

Comment: This solution requires to install the SDC inside the intranet of the company, that I don't have permissions. I only could reach the REST service from my browser as far as I should have the VPN running, but I cannot make calls cross-domains without configuring also the REST service, that I don't have permission either.